# JFileChooser setting a fixed file name

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am making an application that works similar to a text editor with code highlighting.

When I try to save some text, I want a fixed file name to appear on the JFileChooser which will not change while navigating through directories.

The reason I am doing that is because the user is going to save .java files. That file should have the name of the given class. Having the user type the name can only cause mistakes which will slow compiling and doesn't make sense.

code :

```
       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

//intitulé du bouton
chooser.setApproveButtonText("Enregistrer le fichier"); 
//affiche la boite de dialogue 
chooser.showOpenDialog(null); 
chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("fichier"));
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
//chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("fichier"));



    //System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

        String chaine = "";

        String filee = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        String fich = lienTexte.getText();
        File f = new File (filee);
try { 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (f);
    String ligne = "";
for (int i = 0; i < tbl.getRowCount(); i++){
    //pour récupérer l'élément à ligne i et colonne, Tu peux utiliser n'importe quel séparateur 

    ligne = tbl.getValueAt(i,0) + "    " +tbl.getValueAt(i,1) + " " +tbl.getValueAt(i,2)  +tbl.getValueAt(i,3)+  tbl.getValueAt(i,4)+  "  " +tbl.getValueAt(i,5);
    fw.write(ligne);
    //retour chariot
    fw.write("\r\n");
}

fw.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LireFichier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```